# TypeScript exporter from Animate CC

Tags: typescript, createjs, animate-cc

is there any plane to create TypeScript exporter for Animate CC ?
or is a tool that help converting the result JS to TypeScript ?

regards

Comment: typescript is a superset of javascript. As such in most cases javascript code is valid typescript code.

Answer (score 0):

> is a tool that help converting the result JS to TypeScript

Your generated javascript is typescript.

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/why-typescript.html

Here is an image:

[image]

Comment: thanks for you time. what i meant is a definition file for the generated file, so that type-cheeking , code completion work

Answer (score 0):

Animate CC's HTML5 canvas output runs on the CreateJS library. CreateJS already has a Typescript definition file ([see here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/createjs/createjs.d.ts)) but you'll have to script externally for leveraging Typescript. There's no inbuilt support within Animate.